# Параллельная работа обработчиков Telergam бота на python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, vps

Коллеги, вопрос на засыпку.

Разрабатываю телеграм-бота, который выполняет 2 функции:

1. Получение и внесение информации в БД через сообщения пользователя
2. Пишет напоминающие сообщения пользователям с помощью модуля [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) на основании данных, ранее внесенных в БД

По-сути обе эти функции должны работать асинхронно. Так вот вопрос заключается в том, целесообразно ли запускать два отдельных .py файла на vps сервере? Не будут ли конфликтовать два исполнительных файла, работающих с одним ботом? Или все-таки имеет смысл засовывать код в один исполнительный файл и обеспечивать асинхронность с помощью дополнительных модулей? Я вот в раздумьях...

Буду благодарен любому мнению!

Comment: Если два приложения будут работать в режиме LongPolling и подписаны на уведомления, то при подключении второго вылетит ошибка, т.к. телеграм запрещает это делать. При этом, насколько я понимаю, никто не запрещает во втором приложении обращаться к методу api sendMessage...но не знаю может ли telebot просто отослать сообщения без инициализации и подписки.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет! Ну да, так как второй файл не принимает сообщения, а только отправляет уведомления, и polling в нем не запущен, то так и вышло  при тестировании с компа -  запускалось без конфликтов. 
А для send_message не нужен запуск message_handler, он в данном случае нужен только для получения id адресата, а вот для этого мне пришлось создать в БД еще одну колонку...

Comment: Ну, в общем, 2 недели уже два исполнительных файла работают себе нормально и никак не конфликтуют. Сбоев не было, все исправно :)
Вопрос закрыт.